# How to Make a Hair Particle System Follow a Rig

Tags: rigging, particles, hair, rigify

I am making an animated cat for use in Unity, and after creating a hair particle system on the object I attached a rig for animation. When animating though, the hair does not follow the movement of the model.

After investigating for awhile it seems converting the particle system to a mesh is the first option, but when doing that, the colors of my cat model do not transfer onto the mesh, making the hairs all black.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the armature modifier is above the particle system. If you do so the hair should follow the deformations

[image]